# php SOAP request gives internal server error with specific method

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap, wsdl

im trying to build a soap request for the following wsdl method= "GetData"

note that not all the values are required, i've been struggling with this for a week, any help would be very appreciated

```
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "xxxxxxxxxxx"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetData xmlns="xxxxxx">
      <key>string</key>
      <transferDef>
        <Where />
        <OrderBy>
          <OrderByItems>
            <BinaryArithmetic xsi:nil="true" />
            <Categorization xsi:nil="true" />
            <Function xsi:nil="true" />
            <QueryField xsi:nil="true" />
            <QueryForm xsi:nil="true" />
          </OrderByItems>
        </OrderBy>
        <ProjectId>string</ProjectId>
        <DbType>Production or Test</DbType>
      </transferDef>
      <token>
        <Id>guid</Id>
        <LastResponseIdReturned>long</LastResponseIdReturned>
        <FirstResponseIdReturned>long</FirstResponseIdReturned>
        <NumberOfResponsesReturned>long</NumberOfResponsesReturned>
        <DatasetsReturned>long</DatasetsReturned>
        <LastDataSet>boolean</LastDataSet>
        <ProjectId>string</ProjectId>
        <ChangeTrackingVersion>long</ChangeTrackingVersion>
      </token>
    </GetData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: A tool such as SoapUI can automatically generate messages from the WSDL file. That's a good way to find out what your requests should look like.

Comment: if you could provide the wsdl endpoint, would be able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the best way to consume SOAP WS in PHP is to use a WSDL to PHP such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which will generate the classes to construct the request, then to send the request then to handle the response all that using PHP objects. The generated classes are sufficiently intuitive to construct the request. In addition, it uses composer as the autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

kind of resolved the issue, the problem was with the `<token></token>` part.

Since it needs a value of type:guid `<Id>guid</Id>` that as mentioned in the wsdl and xml request, is a dataset created by a .Net library, and it's used to iterate over the samples, it's quite a complicated request, since it needs previous steps to be fulfilled, so i did the request, by omitting the `<token>` section